# How do I create a clickable button or link inside an <a> tag and still be right-clickable?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, anchor

Hello I am currently working a notification dropdown menu and each `<li>` contains a link or an `<a>` tag.

I want to make something like facebook's [notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEycV.jpg).

Now the problem is I want to put a small button or a clickable element inside the `<a>` tag. Or simply **I want to nest an `<a>` inside an `<a>` tag**.
After searching some answers on google I found out that it's impossible to nest it using purely HTML.

Some suggest that put the `<a>` inside the `<div>` with **onclick** event.
But it doesn't make the link right-clickable just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XtH3.jpg).

So how do I make a right-clickable link and inside, it has a clickable button or a link?

Thank you.

**Edit**:
After few more searching, I came up into this code so far.

**HTML:**

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Notification</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <div class="notif-box">
                <a href='#' onclick='testfunction();' style="font-size: 50; float: right; text-decoration: none;">X</a>
                <a href="index.php" id='notif-link-body'></a>
                <b>Notification title here</b>
                <p>Content body here</p>
            </div>    
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
$(".notif-box").click(function() {
    var x = $("#notif-link-body").attr("href");
    window.location = x; 
    return false;
});

function testfunction(){
    alert("It works!");
    return false;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.notif-box {
    width: 250px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.notif-box:hover,
.notif-box:focus {
    color: #262626 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
```

The only problem is whenever I click the "x" button it still redirects me into `index.php` after the alert pops.

Comment: You cannot nest an <a> inside an <a>. Period. You will need a parent element other than <a> to achieve this.

Comment: Okay, so how do i make a parent element that contains a link and enables the user to right click it other than <a>?

Comment: Can you paste your code or some reference?

Comment: Alright. I added it on my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself.
I made the structure like this...

```
<a href="index.php" style="display: block;">//Parent link
 <span class="x-button" style="align: right;">X</span>//The button inside the parent link
 Some text here...
</a>
```

What I did is I made `<a>` **as the parent element** so the user can still **right click** and do something like **open link as a new tab**.

And so to  prevent the browser from triggering the parent element when the user clicked child, I used jquery [hover()](https://www.google.com.ph/url?url=https://api.jquery.com/hover/&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwimy-jprMDQAhUCX5QKHXqcD4EQFggwMAQ&usg=AFQjCNHTOg-7kbuAeiZVin1I_7Is066MZA) and [bind()](http://www.google.com.ph/url?url=http://api.jquery.com/bind/&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjv_PGUrcDQAhVEoZQKHaUnCx8QFggTMAA&usg=AFQjCNHxQDEbqAABDoOfpB4D3-h1GkMdUw) to **disable the parent link when the child is hovered, and re-enables it on mouse leaves.**

```
$(".x-button").hover(function(){//On mouse enter
    var parent = $(this).closest('a');
    parent.bind('click', false);//Disable the parent
}, function(){//On mouse leave
    var parent = $(this).closest('a');
    parent.unbind('click', false);//Re-enable the parent
    parent.blur();//Unfocus the element
});

$(".x-button").click(function() {
    //Do something on click
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, have you tried:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="http://example.com" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Referenced from: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: Nope not this one. I think you did not understand what I am trying to do. I already have dropdown with ajax.
I am just trying to make a clickable button/link inside a link.